# HTML Javascript - setInterval is not running properly

Tags: javascript

I am attaching my code below here for the use of setInterval() function of Javascript.  The code runs only one time afer that it is not running docoment.write to write the value of i in the browser.  Could anyone pls let me know at which place I am wrong with my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function inCreas(){
        var i = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(func,2000);
        function func(){i++;
            document.write("<p>This is the value of i : "+ i +"</p>");
            }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="inCreas()">

    </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried it in IE 8 and Firefox 24.0, but result is same.

Thanks in advance.
Vasudev

Comment: You can't use `document.write` after the document has finished loading. Select the element you want to add the content to and either create the new DOM node(s) and append them or append the extra HTML string to its `innerHTML` property.

Comment: You can't? It does work on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` works only as long as the document is "open". It get's closed when the end `html` tag is reached. After that, calling `document.write` opens an entirely new document.

Now this happens in your page:

1. The original document is created and the onload function is registered.
2. the document is closed
3. the `setInterval` function triggers
4. Because the existing document is already closed, a new one is created, completely overwriting the old one. You can test this by putting some stuff inside the body tag - it will disappear as soon as the `document.write` is executed. This creates an entirely new context - your `setInterval` is also not present any more in the new document.

To achieve the effect you want, you could use `innerHTML` instead - see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dLJ7d/).